# Custom item templates in Visual Studio 2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I would like to be able to add custom item templates in Visual Studio 2010 C++ so that when I go to File > New > File, I can have my own customized headers and source files which contain my layout / comments etc. all ready to go. Currently I am working around this by placing files such as TemplateSource.cpp, TemplateHeader.h, and TemplateTestSuite.cpp in every new project, and then copy + pasting the contents each time I need a new file. However, this is not ideal as it requires some setup, and fiddling around each time I need to use it. It also means that the files need to be able to compile otherwise my build fails, which means I can't have the templates quite how I would like them.

I'm aware that in other languages you can simply go to File > Export Template, but this option is greyed out in C++, for reasons which are beyond me. I've searched for similar questions and found lots of questions but few answers. I myself contributed an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13404502/1227469), but I've since tried the methods described there without success.

Does anyone know a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I went under the Tools->Options menu and an Options menu popped up.
I expanded the "Projects and Solutions" item in the left pane.
I highlighted "General" in the left pane.

The third text box shows a path for User item templates.

Next, I searched the web for "Visual Studio 2012 item templates c++".

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, my question related to VS2010, so it doesn't help me that VS2012 has added the ability to author item templates! But thanks for trying - I suppose I could consider an upgrade, but it seems rather extreme.

Comment: Yes, I've tried the techniques described in the link I gave in my question. I've also looked in the place you suggested, but there is no path for user item templates that I can see - in any case I've previously located that path elsewhere and tried manually creating the template, but the problem is there is no way to specify C++ as the target language in the XML file.

Comment: However, your post prompted me to look into VS2012 a little more and there are a number of other features which might persuade me to make the upgrade (in particular C++ AMP), if I can learn to live with the horrible UI.